# Can I combine 2 games in one ID ad in Admob?

Tags: admob

I have 2 different games in Google Play.

Questions:

- Can I use one id of interstital ad in one campaign in Admob for both of them?
- Is it allowed?
- Will my admob account get disabled if i do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no harm in using the same id for two apps but it is not recommended. Your tracking and statistics analysis will become difficult because you will not know how each of the apps is performing. Better create two separate ad unit ids for the apps.